# How to list all pull subscribers of a google cloud pubsub subscription?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I want to know which services or endpoints are pulling from a pubsub subscription. The reason is that I want to check if any clients has load balanced some messages from the subscription.

Comment: Do you just want the list of subscriptions or do you want the list of subscriber clients? If the latter, what is it that you are looking for? IP address? GCE instance name?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn The latter. I want to get the IP address. Or can I know about summary of history of pulling action? Actually, I want to check if I have only one subscriber running.